# Why do I keep getting "unexpected nil" everywhere?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am making an app with many utilities. Everywhere I turn I get "unexpected nil".

Here's where it is coming up (It has the 'exc_badinstruction' as well):

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

It also comes up in those more complicated code pages ("UIApplicationMain" and others).

Is there one line to fix this?
What exact code should I put in/change to fix this? I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.navigationController!` cannot be nil? If not, then it could be that you force an Optional to unwrap itself while it is nil.

Comment: @Marc What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have to make sure that `self.navigationController` is set in any case. I cannot see if you do so. But it seems you want to access the navigationController before the `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `!` if you don't know what an `Optional` is.
2. Don't put `self.navigationController!.navigationBar....` into  `AppDelegate.swift`.
3. Add a `NavigationController` to your Storyboard.
4. Set the class of the root view controller in the `Idendity Inspector` to your custom ViewController class (Storyboard).
5. Go to your custom ViewController and put `println(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)` into `func viewDidLoad()`.

You should get something like `Optional([<NavigationController.ViewController: 0x7fd7e9e76320>])` as output to the console, which means your ViewController and your NavigationController work well together.

Comment: #6. **Learn what optionals are**. Those who don't understand optionals should not try to program in Swift.